# rules for a tea party

Tags: activities, girls

Im a dad of daughters.  They are native pink/sparkly/rainbow/fairy/mermaid/pink.  As much as it is the opposite of who/what I am, I love them and it is who they are.

So they love "tea parties".

Being a lunk, I don't know the basics.  What are the ground rules?  Is there is "tea parties for dads" or something?  How should I do this so I don't mess it up or teach them bad habits?

Comment: The ground rules are basically the same as if you were playing superheroes, cooking mud pies, building with Legos, or anything: _the kids make the rules_ ;)

Comment: At this point, you're not teaching them how to run a tea party. That's their job to teach you. You're teaching them (by example) how to cooperate, negotiate, share, make decisions, respond and adapt to change, resolve disputes, and tidy up when they're done.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, that is exactly right IMO.  Children are always being taught and dictated to and never get to "control" most aspects of their lives (necessary but sometimes frustrating for them).  I have found that they love being able to be "in charge".  EngrStudent, the best thing you can do is present a willing and positive face to your daughters and let them be the experts.  Ask them what is needed for the party and supply it (within reason).  Then play with them.  You will be building wonderful memories with your daughters.

Comment: I believe that appropriate behavior at a little girls' tea party is discussed in detail here:  http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-h/11-h.htm#link2HCH0007

Comment: @GregHewgill can you make that comment an answer? :)

Comment: @Buzz - I submitted myself to _Alice in Wonderland_ recently and frankly I had to stop because I was more and more getting the thought _WTF was this guy smoking when he wrote that book?_ It's so weird and trippy. Very strange.

Comment: @Torben - Alice is not an acid trip.  It must understand the mind of a child.  The 1999 (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164993) version does a pretty good job - it is meant to show what the adult world looks like to child's eyes.

Comment: Just pointing out that this is tagged for girls, because it's specific to the OP's question, but tea parties can be for any gender.

Answer (score 13):

At this point, you're not teaching your daughters how to run a tea party. That's their job to teach you. You're teaching them (by example) how to cooperate, negotiate, share, make decisions, respond and adapt to change, resolve disputes, and tidy up when they're done.

Don't sweat it if they don't understand what you're trying to show them right now. The important thing is to have fun, laugh with them, be a pawn in their game. They will pick up the nuances of social interactions as you play with them repeatedly over many years.

The details of the tea party are left up to them. They will surely let you know if you're doing it wrong.